# Jquery Hover and Click functions are not working on live server

Tags: jquery, hover, click, handlebars.js

I'm making a web application using Handlebars. I'm using the hover and click function of Jquery (library 1.10.2). Both functions work fine on localhost with dummy JSON data but when i upload the code on the live server and see the effect, None of them are fired. I've used on(), delegate() and what not but none of them are firing.

Any suggestions? My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $(".fav_logo").on('click',function () {
                if ($(this).attr('src') == 'images/like.png')
                {
                    $(this).attr('src')('images/like.png','images/like-selected.png');
                }
                else
                {
                    $(this).attr('src', 'images/like.png');
                }
            });
            $(".fav_logo").on('hover',function ()
            {
                console.log('IT IS HOVERING');
                $(".fav_logo").attr('src','images/like-selected.png');
            }); 

    });
```

Comment: Try putting it in $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: I have done it already. The code is within the $(document).ready block but the problem is that it doesn't respond when uploaded and tested on an online server which is odd.

Comment: Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: No there are no errors. No console logs visible whatsoever. It's like the hover method is not even invoked in any case. And this happens only on LIVE SERVER not on local host. Hover and click work fine on local host and not on live server.